# optimistic locking dynamodb, check before update

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

So I want to update a item in DynamoDB but the parameter I want to update is generated by the process that has to be executed once for a ID, if optimistic locking fails I will still be executing the said process.
How can I avoid this

Imagine this code

```
foo = mapper.get(something)
a = someprocess(foo.varsomething)
foo.savevar(a)
mapper.save(foo)
```

The problem is multiple process can execute someprocess() and that only has to run once

Comment: Could you please try to be more explicit? I'm not sure what you mean by "if optimistic locking fails I will still be executing the said process." A specific example would be great!

Comment: I also failed to understand what you're trying to accomplish and what is exactly the issue or limitation you're facing...

Comment: Edited for further clarification